# MSAccess - 2GB Limit Exceeded or Not Enough Temp Space

Tags: ms-access

I have an AccessDB app that's been working well for many years, with occasional issues w/large datasets.  I have already SPLIT the database to move large, static data (for lookups, etc.) to a backend DB as linked Tables.  Working well.

This week a new error appeared for one of the tool's users. A pretty hefty dataset (50MB Primary, 1.007GB Backend).  When the user attempts a compound sort on the large, linked Backend table, the 2GB Limit / Temp Space message appears.

The error is thrown when the user attempts a compound sort of a 600K record (1GB) table.  I can 100% reproduce on my machine w/32GB (25GB free) RAM and 100GB free diskspace, CPU does not cross 25% during this sort.   Compacting the backend table brings from 1GB to 850MB, but the error persists.

Any thoughts/strategies on how I might deal with this not-so-frequent issue?  I can pre-sort the table as it is fetched from SQL Server to the local AccessDB, but that might be a bandaid, not representing the many possible user modes with this data...

Any Win10 temp memory settings to tweak?

Thanks for any advice.

Mark

Comment: That's the hard limits of Access you are touching. Best advice is to get some space on that SQL Server and run your sorting and filtering there; that could still be controlled from Access.

Comment: Do you really need to move 600K rows, or can the solution work with a subset of this data?

Comment: jbud, yep, need this data, users validate production result against this reference file.  I do think we can prune some of the 50 (!) columns, but none of the records.  I have challenged the owner of that data/process think more deeply how to shrink that table!  

This is a pretty rare occasion, once per year effort among 600-800 similar, but smaller client events each year.

Comment: Hum, try turning off the row locking feature in the access client side. file->options->client settings. You want to un-check the option Open databases by using record level locking. You need to exit and re-start. Note that if other users have the application open during this testing, then your client settings will be ignored. (first user to open back end (linked tables) will force/cause this setting. So, either pull the BE local and re-link or make sure everyone is out. As noted, you have to exit and re-enter for the setting to take effect.